# Intermittent, very high ping to router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a CBN CH6640E router. When I ping the router directly (192.168.0.1), it often exceeds 1000ms, and this can last for a few seconds, or a few minutes. It happens irregularly every few minutes.

- The router is right next to me. I can physically touch the router faster than my computer can ping it.
- Moving the router or the computer does not seem to have an effect.
- Disconnecting devices from the network does not seem to have an effect.
- The signal strength is 90%.
- There are no bluetooth devices active in the house.
- There are at most 3 devices on the network. Disconnecting other devices has no effect.
- There are no hotspot on my channel (2), but 5 devices in channel 1. Many have medium signal strength.
- My home server, which is directly wired to the router, does not experience performance issues.

Comment: Does this also apply when pinging addresses _through_ your router? (Both sides -- something within your LAN to test the Wi-Fi link, as well as something on the WAN side such as your ISP's gateway to test the router's CPU.)

Comment: On the computer with the high ping time, run TCP/IP Reset as follows:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer.  
Test.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Do you have a VPN on the slow-ping computer?

Comment: This is very clearly a wireless issue. From your information you are using the 2.4Ghz band on channel 2. There are numerous reasons why this can be problematic. If the computer is right next to the router just plug it in and get rid of wireless. It doesn’t matter if you are 2” away from the router. The 2.4Ghz band is garbage and channel 2 is not following best practice and chances are numerous devices nearby, outside of your control, are also configured improperly.

Comment: @user1686, yes. Pings to other websites are equally affected.
John I am on MacOS, and this problem affects all wireless devices I use on the network.
Appleoddity, this is the lead I am currently following. The neighbouring channels were a bit crowded. I am switching the channel and looking if it fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information listed above, I narrowed it down to the wireless channel. Using a Wi-Fi analyser, I saw that there were a lot of nearby access points with strong signal on channel 1. I was on channel 2.

I switched to the quietest channel, and it seems to have resolved the issue. I did not have any ping spikes in several days.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've mentioned the exact model (CBN CH6640E). Some routers are able to select the frequency channel based on spectrum occupation. Have a look at the wifi options. I found the manual [here](https://kabel.vodafone.de/static/media/Handbuch_compal_cbn_ch6640e.pdf) but in German. See page 39/54.

As you pointed out, many neighbors have a router that is stuck on a default, static channel for no reason.